# SQL query: get values included from a certain threshold

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this tables:

PATH:

```
idTokenN idPath   token      isTV
   1      p1      test1      true
   2      p1      test2      false
   3      p2      test3      true
   4      p3      test4      false
   5      p3      test5      false
   6      p4      test6      false
   7      p4      test7      true
   8      p4      test8      false
   9      p4      test9      false
   10     p5      test10     true
   11     p5      test11     false
   12     p5      test12     false
```

RELATION:

```
    idTokenN  idTokenN2   rel
       10      11         test
```

I would like to obtain idPath that comprise at least one value Istv "true" and idPath including via a certain threshold, that is, by setting a minimum value and a maximum value. For example, if imposed as a minimum value: 2 and a maximum of 3 idPath long I'll only get between 2 and 3:

```
    idPath  token   isTV    rel
      p1    test1   true    null
      p1    test2   false   null
      p5    test10  true    test
      p5    test11  false   null
      p5    test12  false   null
```

I tried with this query and in part it works, I do not know how to set the range of idPath to take:

```
SELECT path.idPath, path.token, path.isTV,relation.rel 
FROM path 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN relation ON(path.idTokenN=relation.idTokenN)
WHERE path.idPath IN (
        SELECT path.idPath FROM path WHERE path.isTV='true');
```

Comment: You might want to add which DBMS you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not this one ?

```
SELECT path.idPath, path.token, path.isTV,relation.rel
FROM path
LEFT OUTER JOIN relation ON (path.idTokenN=relation.idTokenN)
WHERE path.idPath IN(SELECT DISTINCT path.idPath FROM path WHERE path.isTV='true')
AND path.idPath IN(SELECT DISTINCT path.idPath FROM path GROUP BY path.idPath HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2 AND COUNT(*) <= 3)
```

Comment: Thank you! is there any way to speed up the query? for example first make the selection of the range of values​​, and then only on those use: SELECT DISTINCT path.idPath FROM path WHERE path.isTV='true'

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    path.idPath, 
    path.token, 
    path.isTV,relation.rel 
FROM path 
LEFT OUTER JOIN relation 
    ON(path.idTokenN=relation.idTokenN)
GROUP BY idPath
HAVING SUM(isTV='true')>0
    AND COUNT(DISTINCT path.idTokenN) BETWEEN  2 AND 3
```